# Using extern variable in header and using across multiple projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, extern, multiple-projects

I have 4 projects in a single solution.
I want to use variables defined as extern in one header file globally.
The scenario is  like this:

headerfile.h and function.cpp in project1
mainfile.cpp in project 2

headerfile.h containts:

```
extern int nframes;
```

mainfile.cpp containt:

```
#include "headerfile.h"
int nframes=0;
```

function.cpp containt:

```
//use value of nframes
```

and I am trying to directly access the value of nframes in function.cpp.
But there is a linker error in project 1 : unresolved external symbol "int nframes".

Now, when i define nframes in function.cpp as well, the builds are successful, but the value of nframes is reset to 0 when the control switches from mainfile.cpp to function.cpp.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include mainfile.cpp in each of your projects. The link error is just telling that it cannot find where the variable is defined. Suggest changing the name of mainfile.cpp to GlobalVariables.CPP it should make things clearer to you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'Include'? Thanks for the reply by the way!

Comment: Added to the list of files included in each of your projects (that make up the entire solution).

Comment: Dont you think this will cause further ambiguity?